# Apply JSF rendered attribute to span

Tags: jsf

I am trying to apply a JSF rendered attribute to a span within an h:panelGroup but the span still renders - below is some sample code I am using.

```
<span id="myId" rendered="#{myBean.rendered}" class="groupBox" style="left: 1px; top: 8px; height: 38px; width: 339px;"  />
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont think rendered is a span attribute.

Comment: *Within* a `h:panelGroup`? You don't mean to say `<h:panelGroup id="bla"><h:panelGroup id="blubb" rendered="false"></h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `rendered` attribute is only recognized by JSF components, not by plain HTML elements.

The JSF equivalent of the desired code can be represented by `<h:panelGroup>` or `<h:outputText>`. Both generate a HTML `<span>` element. If you need a `<span>` without text content, exactly like as in your question, just use `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<h:panelGroup id="myId" rendered="#{myBean.rendered}" styleClass="groupBox" style="left: 1px; top: 8px; height: 38px; width: 339px;" />
```

If you need a `<span>` with text content, use `<h:outputText>`. You can specify the text content in its `value` attribute.

Alternatively, if you really, really need to write down a plain HTML `<span>` element yourself for some reason, then you can always move the `rendered` attribute to an `<ui:fragment>` which wraps the entire HTML content.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{myBean.rendered}">
    <span id="myId" class="groupBox" style="left: 1px; top: 8px; height: 38px; width: 339px;" />
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: I used the 2nd solution because I need title attribute that doesn't exist in h:panelGroup

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as well:

```
<p:outputPanel style="display:block">
</p:outputPanel>
```

Ref: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=723